# google guice injecting null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guice, vert.x

I am trying to inject a vertx instance

```
public ServiceBinder(Vertx vertx) {
    this.vertx = vertx;
}
```

I am binding like this

```
@Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Vertx.class).toInstance(this.vertx);
}
```

And I am invoking injection like this

```
public class BaseVerticle extends AbstractVerticle{

@Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
 Guice.createInjector(new ServiceBinder(vertx)).injectMembers(this);
}


}
```

Now I try to inject this in another class

```
public class DelegateFactory {

  @Inject
  private Vertx vertx;
}
```

However here the value of vertx is null. Do I need inject DelegateFactory too?
 I tried annotating DelegateFactory with @Singleton, but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that :

- Your `ServiceBinder` class extends `com.google.inject.AbstractModule`
- Your `DelegateFactory` is binded in your `ServiceBinder` or another guice's `AbstractModule` subclass like that :

  ```
  bind(DelegateFactory.class).in(Singleton.class)
  ```

  or

  ```
  bind(DelegateFactory.class).toInstance(...)
  ```

P.S : it's better to be fail-fast in your `ServiceBinder` constructor :

```
import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

public ServiceBinder(Vertx vertx) {
    this.vertx = requireNonNull(vertx, "vertx must not be null");
}
```